# Index of absolute maximum value of a square matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

How can I find index of absolute maximum value of a square matrix? for example, consider:

```
A = 
    1     -2     1
   -3      2    -3
    2     -5     5
```

MATLAB code should return:

```
row = 3
col = 2
```

Note: If there exist more than one element with absolute maximum value, the code should return one of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the second output from `max` on a flattened matrix (i.e. `A(:)`) and then convert back to subscript indexing using `ind2sub`. I suggest you read up on linear indexing for a proper understanding of how this works.

```
A = [1     -2     1
   -3      2    -3
    2     -5     5]

[~,l] = max(abs(A(:)));

[r,c] = ind2sub(size(A),l)
```

Comment: Okay, that's pretty much my answer.. just posted faster and better.. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can turn the matrix into a vector and determine the position within the matrix from the position within the vector:

```
B = reshape(A,1,size(A,1)*size(A,2))
[~,I] = max(B)
row = mod(I, size(A,1)
col = floor(I / size(A,2))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is easier to read and understand, but will be twice as slow:

```
[row,col]=find(abs(A)==max(abs(A(:))))
```